# Cant take out a number from a group of string - C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I just want to take out a number "865733024598757" from group of string. This looks very frustrated. A simple one i've been trying for an hour, still can't get the solution. What is wrong with my code?

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char imeino[100]="\r\n865733024598757 OK\r\n";
    char data[20];
    for(i=2;i<17;i++)
        {
            //printf("%c",imeino[i]);
            data[i]=imeino[i];
        }
    printf("%s",data);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: So you know already where the numbers are and you really want to extract a substring by indices, right?

Comment: Null termination at the end of data after copy.

Comment: You need to terminate your destination string with `'\0'`. And note that the indices of the characters in `imeono` and `data` are different: What is character 2 in `imeino` will become character 0 in `data`.

Comment: [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) is your friend.

Comment: You mean you wish to extract only digits ?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<15;i++)  {
            data[i]=imeino[i+2];
        }
        data[i] = 0;`

Comment: @MOehm and LP. Thanks guys.. need to learn more basics... how worse i am?... Thank you...

Comment: `strncpy` is your friend too.

Comment: @Bathsheba Im writing code for PIC microcontroller. If i use strncpy, will it take more memory?

Comment: @machine_1 yes. Im extracting only digits...

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll beat `strncpy`; which could well be implemented in assembler on your platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char imeino[100]="\r\n865733024598757 OK\r\n";
    char data[20];
    for(i=2;i<17;i++)
        {
            data[i-2]=imeino[i];
        }
    data[i-2] = '\0';
    printf("%s",data);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see:

1. Index of data must start from 0. i starts from 2 then you must substract it to index data array.
2. You must `NUL` terminate your string.

Many better implementation could be used. Take a look at

- [strok](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)
- [memcpy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm)
- [strncpy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncpy.htm)

Comment: The null terminator must also be at `i - 2`. (Maybe it's more intuitive to place the offset on `imeino` and have the loop run from zero up to the substring length? That would also make it easier to spot the new string length at a glance.)

Answer (score 2):

Correct working code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char imeino[100] = "\r\n865733024598757 OK\r\n";
    char data[20] = {0};
    for (i = 2; i< 17; i++)
    {
        //printf("%c",imeino[i]);
        data[i-2] = imeino[i];
    }
    printf("%s", data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LPs, all members are initialized to `0`, this code seems correct to me.

Comment: @LPs: It does. When some, but not not all elements of an aray are explicitly initialised, the remaining elements are initialised to zero. The undefined behaviour would just be an uninitialised array, i.e. just `char imeino[20];`.

Comment: Yes, My fault. Deleted.